# iotop for a particular process

Tags: linux, io

When running

```
sudo iotop --only
```

I get all process performing IO. I want to receive stats for a particular process. When I run

```
sudo iotop --only -p pid
```

I receive following error:

```
CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT not enabled in kernel, cannot determine SWAPIN and IO %
```

How can I remove that error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo) and iotop 0.6.

When running iotop -p  for certain pids, such as my java tomcat process I see:

```
   ... SWAPIN     IO>   ...

   ... ?unavailable?    ...

   ...
```

CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT not enabled in kernel, cannot determine SWAPIN and IO %

For other pids it works OK.

With a problem pid, if I run:

```
    iotop -b -n 100 -P | grep ^pid
```

to run iotop in batch mode then I see:

```
   ... 0.00 %  0.00 % ...
```

rather than the ?unavailable?. So, the iotop -b approach might be a workaround. I've not yet seen any values other than 0.00 %, so I can't be sure this displays real values.

A Red Hat page, https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3726051, reports a bug that says the error message is misleadingly displayed if an invalid pid or 'the' kernel pid is used.